# Martingale that converges almost surely to $-\infty$.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

The question is as follows:

> Exercise 5.2.4. Give an example of a martingale $X_n$ with $X_n \to -\infty$ a.s. Hint: Let
>   $X_n = \xi_1 + · · · + \xi_n$, where the $\xi_i$ are independent (but not identically distributed) with $E\xi_i = 0$.

My guess is that we should not make $\xi_n$ having a distribution such that it has zero expectation but are more and more likely to be negative. For example, we can have
$\mathbb{P}(\xi_n = 1) = 1/n$ and $\mathbb{P}(\xi_n = \frac {-1} {n-1}) = \frac {n-1} n$. But I am not sure how to prove $\sum \xi_n \to -\infty$.

Comment: Could you please state which book this exercise of from? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: you can let each $\xi_n$ be either $-1$ or positive (and like you said, each with zero expectation and more and more likely to be negative) and if you choose the
distributions right then you can use the [Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) to make sure that the probability that infinitely many $\xi_n$'s are positive is zero.

Comment: I see. How about let $\xi_{n}$ be $-1$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}$,
and be $2^{n}-1$with probability $1/2^{n}$.Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/2^{n}<\infty,$we
have $\mathbb{P}\{\xi_{n}>0 \, \text{i.o.}\}=0$. In other words,
$\mathbb{P}\{\xi_{n}<0 \, \text{i.o.}\}=1$. So we have $\sum_{m=1}^n \xi_n \to
-\infty$.

Comment: @ablmf Yep, that would work.