# Martingale theory: Collection of examples and counterexamples

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, martingales, big-list

The aim of this question is to collect interesting examples and counterexamples in martingale theory. There is a huge variety of such (counter)examples available here on StackExchange but I always have a hard time when I try to locate a specific example/question. I believe that it would be a benefit to make this knowledge easier to access. For this reason I would like to create a (big) list with references to related threads.

Martingale theory is a broad topic, and therefore I suggest to focus on time-discrete martingales $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. I am well aware that this is still a quite broad field. To make this list a helpful tool (e.g. for answering questions) please make sure to give a short but concise description of each (counter)example which you list in your answer.

Related literature:

- Jordan M. Stoyanov: Counterexamples in Probability, Dover.
- Joseph P. Romano, Andrew F. Siegel: Counterexamples in probability and statistics, CRC Press.

Comment: An example which I like but not found in text books is the following: consider $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and let $X_n(\omega)=n$ if $0<\omega <\frac 1 n$, and $0$ otherwise. This sequence happens to be a martingale which converges almost surely but not in the mean (hence not uniformly integrable).

Answer (score 35):

convergence results:

- [pointwise convergence of martingale $M_n$ does not imply $\sup_n \mathbb{E}(M_n^+)<\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2515053/36150) (this means that the converse of the martingal convergence theorem does not hold true)
- [martingale which converges almost surely but not in $L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2200141/36150) (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/971921/36150))
- [martingale $(M_n)_n$ such that $M_n \to -\infty$ almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/308677/36150) (consider $-M_n$ to get a martingale such that $M_n \to \infty$ a.s.)
- [non-trivial martingale which converges almost surely to $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309243/36150) (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2917185/36150))
- [martingale which converges in probability but not almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2200311/36150) (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965136/martingale-oscillating-between-three-values/2966240#2966240))
- [martingale which converges in distribution but not almost surely/in probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2978806/36150) (see also Section 2.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.07833.pdf))

uniform integrability:

- [martingale $(M_n)_n$ for which $M_{\infty} = \lim_n M_n$ exists a.s. but $\mathbb{E}(M_{\infty} \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \neq M_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2917133/36150) (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/971921/36150) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3012804/36150); note that such a martingale cannot be uniformly integrable and cannot converge in $L^1$)
- [uniformly integrable martingale $(M_n)_n$ such that $\mathbb{E}\left( \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |M_n| \right) = \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1547360/36150).

sample path behaviour:

- [oscillating martingale with bounded sample paths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965136/martingale-oscillating-between-three-values/2966240#2966240)
- [non-trivial martingale which is constant with positive probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2804153/36150)
- [martingale which is non-constant and non-negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3014850/36150)

Stopping times (Optional stopping/sampling theorem):

- [martingale $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and stopping time $\tau$ such that $\mathbb{E}(M_{\tau}) \neq \mathbb{E}(M_0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2402280/36150)
- [martingale $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and stopping time $\tau$ such that $M_{n \wedge \tau} \to M_{\tau}$ almost surely but not in $L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2200311/36150) (see the very first part of the the linked answer)
- [martingale $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and stopping time $\tau$ such that $\tau<\infty$ almost surely and $\mathbb{E}(\tau)=\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2980871/36150)

Other

- [stochastic process $(M_n)_n$ which satisfies $\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} \mid M_n) = M_n$ for all $n$ but which is not a martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1186859/36150)
- [martingale which is not bounded in $L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1998143/36150)

Comment: Any idea why it is called a "martingale"?

Comment: @Michael, see example 2 [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Martingale).